# How do you prevent a page from resetting after redirecting to it?

Tags: php, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I am developing a website and I have come to a point where after the sign-up page and back-end checking that the e-mail is not used twice, I need to send the form data to the main webpage and redirect to it. After testing, I found that the data sends but after redirecting the page resets. Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

The main webpage:

```
<?php
if (isset($_REQUEST['data1'])) {
    $data = json_decode($_REQUEST['data1']);
    
    $email = $data->email ;
    
    mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

}else{
    echo "Something went wrong.";
    exit();
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="semantic.css">
</head>
<div class="ui five item menu">
    <a class="active item">My House</a>
    <a href="news.php" class="item">News</a>
    <a href="chatroom.php" class="item">Chatroom</a>

    <a href="finances.php" class="item">Finances</a>

    <a href="gallery.php" class="item">Photo Gallery</a>
  </div>




<div>

<h1>Hello <?php echo $email?> </h1>



</div>
```

The sign-up page ajax:

```
function senddata() {

var params1 = new Object();

params1.email = document.getElementById('email').value;
data1 = "data1="+JSON.stringify(params1)


var httpx = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url1 = 'main.php';
httpx.open('POST', url1, true);       
httpx.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');


httpx.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(httpx.readyState == 4 && httpx.status == 200) {
        window.location = "main.php"
    
    }}

httpx.send(data1);

    
}

function conn(){
var params = new Object();
params.ho_id = document.getElementById('ho_id').value;
params.fname = document.getElementById('fname').value;
params.lname = document.getElementById('lname').value;
params.email = document.getElementById('email').value;
params.pass = document.getElementById('pass').value;
params.genders = document.getElementById('genders').value;

data = "data="+JSON.stringify(params)


var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = 'blah.php';

http.open('POST', "blah.php", true);

http.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

http.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
        if (this.responseText == "Failed.Email.") {
            document.getElementById('ho_id').classList = "fields"
            document.getElementById('email').classList = "fields-error"
            document.getElementById('email').setAttribute('title', "Already in use.")
            alert("Email is already in use.")
        } else if (this.responseText == "Failed.ID.") {
            document.getElementById('ho_id').setAttribute('title', "Already in use.")
            document.getElementById('ho_id').classList = "fields-error"
            document.getElementById('email').classList = "fields"
            alert("ID is already in use.")
            
        }else{
            senddata()
            
            
        }
    }
}

http.send(data);





}
```

I alerted the response text and there was no error, but after substituting that for "window.replace('main.php')" or "window.location = 'main.php" I get the "Something went wrong." error from the "if/else" in the main webpage because "data1" was no longer available.

Comment: I think this might be a use case for Sessions

Comment: You need to pass the email with data1 to your website, but you pass no data at all: `window.location = "main.php"` - add at least `?data1=` and the urlencoded JSON with the email property+value to it as otherwise it will remain empty. Sessions (via Cookies) might be easier, as what  ADyson commented, my comment is just the bare minimum from your code that is required.

Comment: Isn't the data passed where it says "http.send(data1)"?

Comment: @ADyson Can I get an example?

Comment: @YohannesTimket: Yes, but it must be as well here: `window.location = "main.php"`

Comment: @hakre I tried it and it returned a "state must be open" error. After putting "httpx.open(...)", it returned a "failed to finish loading" error (these errors are from the chrome console by the way). I realized that there would be an endless loop because now I would have to add "httpx.onreadystate".

Comment: Looks like that there is more than a single issue with the code, hard to reason about it then on SO.

Comment: @YohannesTrinket https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/php-tutorial/php-sessions.php ...there are many other tutorials available too

Comment: _"Isn't the data passed where it says "http.send(data1)"?"_ - yes, for that one request to `main.php`, that you are making via `XMLHttpRequest`. But then you make the browser make a _second_ request, via `window.location = "main.php"` - and that is completely independent from the first one. (Plus request methods are different, the browser will make a GET request the second time. But even if methods were the same, these are two still separate requests, that do not have any direct connection between them.)